# How can I get variable values from a plot?

Tags: python, plotting, matplotlib

I would like to know if there is any way in python to automatically determine the values of point a and b marked in the graph below. Said a different way, finding the values when my plot shows a marked decrease or after a marked increase.

[image: two muppets]

This is the source code of my plot if it is helpful:

````
#load data

min_duration = data['Time_Secondes'].min()
max_duration = data['Time_Secondes'].max()
xr_ = list(range(min_duration,  max_duration,  60))
y_ = []

for i in range(0,(len(xr_)-1)):
    Time_proba_ = np.logical_and(data['Time_Secondes'].values >= xr_[i], data['Time_Secondes'].values < xr_[i+1])
    Time_proba_1_ = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(data['Time_Secondes'].values >= xr_[i], data['Time_Secondes'].values < xr_[i+1]), data['outcome'].values==1)
    y_.append(sum(Time_proba_1_ )/sum(Time_proba_))


import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(xr_[1:len(xr_)], y_)

```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is a function of your data, not of `matplotlib`. I would think of this as a second derivative problem -- you care about differences in slopes of successive lines.

1. Sort a dataframe `[x,y]` by `x` values, in increasing order.
2. Calculate the first discrete derivative `delta1 = (y[i+1] - y[i]) / (x[i+1] - x[i])`. This tells you the slope of each line.
3. Now you can do one of two things, depending on what you want to identify.

   1. Calculate the second discrete derivative `delta2 = (delta1[i+1] - delta1[i]) / (x[i+1] - x[i])`.
   2. Calculate the difference of successive slopes `diff = delta1[i+1] - delta1[i]`
4. Select all `i`s for which absolute value of {`diff` or `delta2`} is greater than a certain threshold.

Selecting all `x` values for which `np.abs(x[i]) > threshold` will give you the x-locations of these large changes in slope.

Here's an example I just coded up,for identifying the jump in a jump function $x / |x|$.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_data = 100

x = np.random.uniform(-10,10,n_data)
y = x / np.abs(x)

delta = [0] * n_data
diff = [0] * n_data

data = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
data = data.sort_values('x')

for i in range(n_data - 1):
    a, fa = data.iloc[i]
    b, fb = data.iloc[i+1]
    diff_quot = (fb - fa) / (b-a)
    delta[i] = diff_quot

data['delta'] = delta

for i in range(n_data - 1):
    a, fa, da = data.iloc[i]
    b, fb, db = data.iloc[i+1]
    dd = db - da
    diff[i] = np.abs(dd)

data['diff'] = diff

plt.plot(data['x'],data['y'])
plt.plot(data['x'],data['diff'])

threshold = 1
jumps = [dd > threshold for dd in diff]
```

Here is the jump function, whose jump we might want to locate

[image: jump function]

Here is a graph of the differences in slopes, where we see the jump is located near `x = 0`

[image: diff function]

Comment: Depends on whether the asker has data or the plot. Maybe the asker has plots and needs to determine the data from it. But I have to tell you that's a good answer

Comment: @JuanEstebandelaCalle I figured based on the way the plot was defined that the asker had data. You're right though, and if this is entirely dependent on a picture I don't really have an answer. Thanks for the compliment :)

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, for your answer. I do appreciate it. Actually, I have data frame contains 2 columns: Time that gamers spent on seconds and their scores (correct and incorrect). I want to know the range of time when the probability of  score can be 0 , i.e I want to get all the markable decrease on the plot .  I dont know wich fonction can help me.

Comment: I want to get the range on x-axis . for example in the plot picture I would like to get as result 450---600  where I have markable decrease

Comment: @Nirmine But in your picture 450--600 has a net increase -- it's not a markable decrease. There's a decrease between (I would say) 425 -- 475, and an increase from 475 -- 600.

Comment: effectively Andrew, I want something similar to that, How to get x-axis value of every decrease where Y < 0.5 and every Increase where Y > 0.5   i.e. the range from ~~ 475---550

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is not changes in slope, but extreme slopes. I would do this by picking off all x values with `np.abs(delta[i]) > threshold`. This will give all steep lines.

Comment: Thank Andrew I will try It I do appreciate your help